# Django access to subclasses items from abstract class

Tags: python, django

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    ....
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Cat(models.Model, Animal):
    ...

class Dog(models.Model, Animal):
    ....
```

I want to be able to return all instances of querysets of all the subclasses of Animal. Lets say I have a function called `allData` which returns an array/list of all the subclasses querysets.

For example:

```
x = animal.allData()[0] # should return the first element in the array.
```

I don't mind how we do this, using modules like `django-model-utils` or not. I just want to be able to return all the subclasses querysets.

Comment: Note that neither of the answers here seem to address the fact this is an abstract base model. The answers assume a concrete base model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible in one query. You have two options, one use to use [`django-model-utils`](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) or you can use [`django_polymorphic`](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic).

Polymorphic is better suited to your task, however `django-model-utils` is made by a very prominent member of the django community and as such has a lot of good support.

If I had to choose, I'd choose `django-model-utils` since its made by a member of the django team, and thus will be supported. Polymorphic is supported by divio, which is a private company that heavily uses django based in Switzerland.

As for how to select Sub-classes. You need to do two things using `django-model-utils`. Firstly, you need to change the `objects` variable in your model to `InheritanceManager()` like so (adapted from docs):

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Place(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = InheritanceManager()

class Restaurant(Place):
    # ...

class Bar(Place):
    # ...

nearby_places = Place.objects.filter(location='here').select_subclasses()
for place in nearby_places:
    # "place" will automatically be an instance of Place, Restaurant, or Bar
```

The code above will return all `Bar`s and `Restaurant`s because it uses the `select_subclasses`.

Comment: Does it really work for abstract models? I try to implement it in my project and this line `queryset = MyAbstractModel.objects.select_subclasses()`  causes an error `AttributeError: Manager isn't available; MyAbstractModel is abstract`
Do you have any idea why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: I don't think django-model-utils works for abstract base models.    I think this answer is valid for MTI (multiple table inheritance), not for abstract base models/inheritance

Comment: What about filtering by child fields? For instance, if only Bar will have 'Boolean grill' field and i need to filter all places by that field? Like Places.objects.select_subclasses().filter(grill__isnull=False) ? I get an error 'django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'grill' into field.' Choices are: (...further all PARENT fields listed)  ----> btw here there is appropriate question ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329605/how-to-filter-on-subclass-fields-in-an-inheritancequeryset-avoiding-a-fielderro

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [django_polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic)

Example from project docs:

When we store models that inherit from a `Project` model...

```
>>> Project.objects.create(topic="Department Party")
>>> ArtProject.objects.create(topic="Painting with Tim", artist="T. Turner")
>>> ResearchProject.objects.create(topic="Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor="Dr. Winter")
```

...and want to retrieve all our projects, the subclassed models are returned:

```
>>> Project.objects.all()
[ <Project:         id 1, topic "Department Party">,
  <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner">,
  <ResearchProject: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor "Dr. Winter"> ]
```