# How to filter on subclass fields in an InheritanceQueryset (avoiding a FieldError)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

On the filtering action of a datatable I'm getting the following issue:
I have an inheritance queryset containing 2 Models inheriting from the Equipment Model: Motors & PU:

```
class Equipment(EngineeringItem):
    ...
class Motor(Equipment):
    cos_phi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
class PU(Equipment):
    cos_phi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)


<InheritanceQuerySet [<Motor: M624>, <PU: U103>, <Motor: I501>, 
'...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

When applying the following filter q (django.db.models.Q object):

```
<Q: (AND: ('cos_phi__icontains', '0.7'))>

queryset = queryset.filter(q)
```

I get the following field error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'cos_phi' into field. Choices are:...

With the fields of 'Equipment' indicated. Clearly I can only filter on the Equipment fields, but I'm looking for a way to still filter on 'cos_phi', as all items in the queryset have this field (This filter is applied when loading the data)

Comment: If all of the models have it shouldn't this field be in the `Equipment` model instead?

Comment: Good question, but no: Not all equipment have this property. But all instances ending up in this queryset do.

Comment: That just means your models need a common ancestor in between, something like `EquipmentWithCosPhi(Equipment)` and then `Motor(EquipmentWithCosPhi)`

Comment: Is there a clean way in inserting this afterwards?

Comment: First add the `EquipmentWithCosPhi` model and also inherit from it(along with `Equipment`) in your other models. Set the One to One field explicitly with `null=True` like so: `models.OneToOneField(EquipmentWithCosPhi, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True, null=True)`. Next migrate. After this do a data migration and create instances of `EquipmentWithCosPhi` for each of your other models instances. Then remove the inheritance with `Equipment` from your other models and `null=True` from the one to one field. Note: I have not tested this, also take backups of your database before trying.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just to understand all posibilities: Any idea if I can split up an InheritanceQuerySet into different regular querysets per subclass? The InheritanceQueryset has an attribute 'subclasses' which contains a list of the subclass names, so this plausible..

Comment: This actually seem to boil down to: can I change a Equipment queryset (parent model) to a Motor queryset (child model)

Comment: Did you solve it?